How to split the full name into first last and middle name
Input



Name




Anubhav Sharma


Rakesh Kumar Sharma


Muthiah Srinivas attapatu Murlidharan



Actual Output



first_name
middle_name
last_name




Anubhav
Sharma



Rakesh
Kumar
Sharma


Muthiah
Srinivas
attapatu



Expected Output



first_name
middle_name
last_name




Anubhav

Sharma


Rakesh
Kumar
Sharma


Muthiah
Srinivas attapatu
Murlidharan



df = df.withColumn("arr", F.split(F.col("Name"), " "))
    
df = (df.withColumn('FirstName', F.arr.getItem(0))
        .withColumn('MiddleName', F.arr.getItem(1))
        .withColumn('LastName', F.arr.getItem(2)))




The problem is with the middle name for that my code is incorrect

Your question as asked is fundamentally impossible to solve. Please clarify what specifically you mean by first name, middle name and last name and what edge cases you need to cover.

You are only considering a 3 part case in your code, while obviously there are other cases that you are not handling. You can implement the logic as below based on the number of parts a Name can have:
name_schema = StructType([
    StructField("first_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("middle_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("last_name", StringType(), True)
])

@F.udf(returnType=name_schema)
def split_name(name):
    parts = name.split()
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return (parts[0], "", "")
    elif len(parts) == 2:
        return (parts[0], "", parts[1])
    elif len(parts) == 3:
        return (parts[0], parts[1], parts[2])
    else:
        return (parts[0], " ".join(parts[1:-1]), parts[-1])

# Apply the UDF to split names
df = df.withColumn("split_name", split_name("Name"))

df = df.withColumn("first_name", F.col("split_name.first_name")) \
       .withColumn("middle_name", F.col("split_name.middle_name")) \
       .withColumn("last_name", F.col("split_name.last_name")) \
       .drop("split_name")

Output:
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|Name                                 |first_name|middle_name      |last_name  |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|Anubhav Sharma                       |Anubhav   |                 |Sharma     |
|Rakesh Kumar Sharma                  |Rakesh    |Kumar            |Sharma     |
|Muthiah Srinivas attapatu Murlidharan|Muthiah   |Srinivas attapatu|Murlidharan|
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+


Like in the code you shared, you don't need to worry about handling different cases separately:

Split the given Name column into an array
For extracting the first name, you need to extract the first element from the array
Analogue, the last element from the array will be the last name
For extracting the middle name(s), slice the array to get all elements between the first and last names (if any), then join them into a single string

df = df.withColumn("arr", F.split(F.col("Name"), " "))

df = df.withColumn('first_name', F.col('arr').getItem(0))

df = df.withColumn('last_name', F.col('arr').getItem(F.size(F.col('arr')) - 1))

df = df.withColumn(
    'middle_name', 
    F.expr("slice(arr, 2, size(arr) - 2)")
)  
df = df.withColumn(
    'middle_name',
    F.concat_ws(" ", F.col('middle_name'))
)


df.drop('arr')
df.select("Name", "first_name", "middle_name", "last_name").show(truncate=False)

The output of the above code is:
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|Name                                 |first_name|middle_name      |last_name  |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|Anubhav Sharma                       |Anubhav   |                 |Sharma     |
|Rakesh Kumar Sharma                  |Rakesh    |Kumar            |Sharma     |
|Muthiah Srinivas attapatu Murlidharan|Muthiah   |Srinivas attapatu|Murlidharan|
+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+

⚠️Please be aware that this only covers the edge cases you provided in your example: first and last names, and optionally one or more middle names.
